# Twitter app returns wrong value in onActivityResult

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm composing a Tweet and then launch Twitter app to tweet it like that:

```
intent = new TweetComposer.Builder(getFragmentActivity())
                        .text(viewHolder.etShareText.getText().toString())
                        .url(contentUrl)
                        .image(imageUri)
                        .createIntent();
```

It worked for a long time, and it still works, I'm able to post a tweet to my profile, but some time ago every action was resulted with **RESULT_CANCELED** in my **onActivityResult()** method despite the actual result was successfull.
Maybe something had changed in Twitter API? How to handle results now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in this case onActivityResult() usage may not true way. To catch composing result, like [vijikumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586765/3341089) said, we should use BroadcastReceiver. But this information is not enough for us. Because in many cases, twitter composing ways are confused with each other. Like [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/compose-tweets) said ; there are two ways to compose tweets :

- Launch the Twitter application’s Tweet Composer
- Launch the Twitter Kit Native Composer

If you prefer to use first way, as long as i see, there is not a healthy method to catch composing result using BroadcastReceiver, onActivityResult or etc.

BroadcastReceiver method does not work using first way. But if you prefer to use second way, you can catch composing result using BroadcastReceiver in a healthy position. You shouldn't think that first way is not important. I am going to talk about first way briefly.

To do these above ;

**Second Way**

Add below repository and dependencies in your app level gradle file

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
}

compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.1'
```

Then add below BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MyResultReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (TweetUploadService.UPLOAD_SUCCESS.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      // success
    } else if (TweetUploadService.UPLOAD_FAILURE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      // failure
    } else if (TweetUploadService.TWEET_COMPOSE_CANCEL.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      // cancel
    }
  }
}
```

Then add your BroadcastReceiver to the application manifest file like below

```
<receiver
  android:name=".MyResultReceiver"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_SUCCESS"/>
    <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_FAILURE"/>
    <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TWEET_COMPOSE_CANCEL"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

As last, to open the composer screen, start ComposerActivity using below code block

```
final TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager()
    .getActiveSession();
final Intent intent = new ComposerActivity.Builder(YourActivity.this)
    .session(session)
    .text("Love where you work")
    .hashtags("#twitter")
    .createIntent();
startActivity(intent);
```

When you use this way, you will catch composer result in BroadcastReceiver.

I will not share any code block about **First Way**. But why can we need the first way ? Actually first way contains very rich content but as long as i see, it does not support to catch result. So second way is enough for us in many cases. ***however if Twitter app does not exist the device, second way will crash because of session.*** In this case, we should use first way to open composer screen in internet browser. So we should use both ways but like you see that first one is more effective than second one.

NOTE : Do not forget to add the twitter kit initialization configurations and authentication mechanisms please.

Comment: I tried your code and getting an error: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TwitterSession must not be null".

Comment: This is so normal. I explained that " if Twitter app does not exist the device, second way will crash because of session". So if your device does no have the twitter app as created, you will get that error called 'TwitterSession must not be null'.  So you should use both ways together. if your device has twitter app, use second way, else use first way.

Comment: To check twitter existing, you may use below code block:
        boolean isExistTwitterClient = false;
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = getContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
            if (TextUtils.equals(packageInfo.packageName, "com.twitter.android")) {
                isExistTwitterClient = true;
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        }

Answer (score 0):

Use BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class MyResultReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (TweetUploadService.UPLOAD_SUCCESS.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            // success
            final Long tweetId = intentExtras.getLong(TweetUploadService.EXTRA_TWEET_ID);
        } else {
            // failure
            final Intent retryIntent = intentExtras.getParcelable(TweetUploadService.EXTRA_RETRY_INTENT);
        }
    }
}
```

In manifest

```
<receiver
  android:name=".MyResultReceiver"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_SUCCESS"/>
    <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_FAILURE"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually this broadcast receiver does not catch upload event.

Comment: could you please show how you send a tweet? I've tried TwitterComposer through **builder.show()** and by **Intent** - both don't trigger TweetUploadService, I admit

Comment: Use this version `compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'`